Is admin right needed for Bluetooth piaring?
My work machine is a M2 Air running Sequoia 15.1. A few weeks ago, my user account was granted admin access so I could easily setup the required development tools. Now, per internal company policy, the admin privillege is removed.
Just noticed another strange thing: couldn't pair with any Bluetooh device (here, Bluetooth Device most likely refers to my Bluetooth mouse)

If I click "ATH-SQ1TW", no connect button etc appear. This doesn't occur when I still had admin right. Now it makes me wonder: does Bluetooth pairing require admin privillege?

Bluetooth paring doesn't require admin rights. Is your Mac managed by the company and do they have BT pairing disabled for all users?

Is my Mac managed by the company? Yes. Do they have BT pairing disables for all users? I speculate they did, but nevertheless will ask the IT team about this. On my previous companies, my Mac user account was admin, so installing apps or tweaking system configuration was easy.

@nohillside Yep, Bluetooth pairing doesn't require admin right. After rebooting my Mac a few times, finally pairing with the TWS work. And most likely there's an issue with my mouse, because pairing works fine with another mouse. Weird.
